How to compile testsuite for libgomp coming from GNU gcc git?
Source git : git://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git
Directory structure :
gcc/libgomp/testsuite$ ls
config  lib        libgomp.c++           libgomp.fortran   libgomp.oacc-c    libgomp.oacc-c-c++-common  libgomp-site-extra.exp.in    Makefile.am  oe-logs
flock   libgomp.c  libgomp.c-c++-common  libgomp.graphite  libgomp.oacc-c++  libgomp.oacc-fortran       libgomp-test-support.exp.in  Makefile.in  oe-workdir
There is no Makefile or configure.ac
It has Makefile.am Makefile.in
Cross-compiling on x86-64 host for armv8-2a
How can I compile this testsuite?

http://gcc.gnu.org/install/ Found in https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=INSTALL/README;h=38574d3b763a2accac8846427b0df0bdd92f99f7;hb=HEAD
